# Having pagination issue in Vue / Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to paginate fetched data in Vue. But having a problem:

### Question Updated

> Error in render: "TypeError: this.estates.filter is not a function"

Do I missing something?

### Pagination.vue

```js
           
 Data(){
  return {    
           meta_data: {
                last_page: null,
                current_page: 1,
                prev_page_url: null
           }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchEstates();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchEstates(page = 1) {
            axios.get('/ajax', {
                params: {
                    page
                }}).then((response) => {
                this.estates = response.data;
                this.meta_data.last_page = response.data.last_page;
                this.meta_data.current_page = response.data.current_page;
                this.meta_data.prev_page_url = response.data.prev_page_url;
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        one: function () {
            let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
                return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.includes(this.keyword)) &&
                (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
                (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});
  
 /// rest of the code....
```

if you need more information please tell me.

Comment: json is good, what is not working here exactly?

Comment: i am really really not sure.... @DusanRadovanovic this pagination make me crazy in the end.

Comment: You should loop throw `estates` not `meta_data.last_page` in  `v-for="page in meta_data.last_page"`

Comment: I am having this error in the console: ` TypeError: this.estates.filter is not a function,` I guess this is why I can't display the data @DusanRadovanovic

Comment: Show me how does `console.log(response)` look like when you receive the response

Comment: it looks just fine I am getting the data https://imgur.com/a/LODRbTn as you see. But can not displaying. because of this error.  `TypeError: this.estates.filter is not a function` @DusanRadovanovic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187706/discussion-between-barbie-and-dusan-radovanovic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the line

`this.estates = response.data;`

to

`this.estates = response.data.data;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = \DB::table('allestates')->paginate(5);
    $response = [
        'pagination' => [
            'total' => $data->total(),
            'per_page' => $data->perPage(),
            'current_page' => $data->currentPage(),
            'last_page' => $data->lastPage(),
            'from' => $data->firstItem(),
            'to' => $data->lastItem()
        ],
        'data' => $data
    ];
    return response()->json($response);
```